# Generating combinations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains groups ('G1', 'G2' etc) and a table that contains persons ('P1', 'P2', etc...) and a m:m relation ship between them, so one user can belong to several groups, and one group consists of several users.

I have a rule that is satisfied only if a certain number of members of each group is present (i.e. at least 2 members of G1 and at least 1 member of G2 must be present), and I have a list od users that are present. One person cannot fulfil more than one requirement, so if P1 and P2 are members of both G1 and G2, the rule still needs a third person which can be a member of either G1 or G2.

Any ideas how can this be done in SQL Server?

---

Creation scripts:

```
create table Groups (GroupID int, Name nvarchar(100))
insert into Groups values (1, 'First')
insert into Groups values (2, 'Second')
insert into Groups values (3, 'Third')

create table Persons (PersonID int, Name nvarchar(100))
insert into Persons values (1, 'One')
insert into Persons values (2, 'Two')
insert into Persons values (3, 'Three')
insert into Persons values (4, 'Four')
insert into Persons values (5, 'Five')
insert into Persons values (6, 'Six')

create table PersonGroups (PersonID int, GroupID int)
-- p1 and p2 are members of g1
insert into PersonGroups values (1, 1)
insert into PersonGroups values (2, 1)
-- p2, p3 and p4 are members of g2
insert into PersonGroups values (2, 2)
insert into PersonGroups values (3, 2)
insert into PersonGroups values (4, 2)
-- p2, p4, p5 and p6 are members of g3
insert into PersonGroups values (2, 3)
insert into PersonGroups values (4, 3)
insert into PersonGroups values (5, 3)
insert into PersonGroups values (6, 3)
```

So, If a rule needs one person from each group to be present (1,3,5), (1,2,3), (2,3,4) would be valid, and (3, 5, 6) would not be valid.

Comment: Is this a one time query for a one time rule, or do you need this rule to be dynamic on the number of groups and persons ? Because I don't think SQL is good for this kind of stuff.

Comment: This is invariably possible in SQL alone, but it is (as im sure you are aware) much more suited to set based operations. This sounds like business logic, which belongs in a business layer.

Comment: @Scorpi0, @Jamiec: This will be a procedure that will vary on the persons, the groups and also the rules. This must be SQL - tried a lot to convince the client, but failed.

Comment: @Sweko - started to work on this but got hung up, it will take some time.  You may be better off with an application approach, since multi-layered conditional logic may not be easy in pure SQL.  Think about using a CTE with a TOP clause, and a UNION to make it recursive.

Comment: @Sweko - Is there a limit to the number of groups you will be checking?

Comment: How are you storing or passing the "rules"?

Comment: @JNK: No, but it wont be a large number - you might recurse it in a CTE, I'm trying something along those lines myself.

Comment: @Tom H: The rules are stored in a Rules (RuleID) and RuleDetails (RuleID, GroupID, NumberPresent) tables, I did not include those in the scripts, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Create header table for rules

```
create table #ruleset (Id int, name varchar(100))
insert into #ruleset
select 1,'At least 1 person from each group'
```

Create child table for each rule having many entries for each group.

```
drop table #ruleset_grouprules
create table #ruleset_Grouprules(Id int identity(1,1), RuleId int, 
     GroupID int, MinUsers int, MaxUsers int)
insert into #ruleset_Grouprules (RuleId, groupId, MinUsers, MaxUsers)
select 1,1,1,null
union all
select 1,2,1,null
union all
select 1,3,1,null
```

- You can use NULL in the MinUsers column to represent no minimum amount
- You can use NULL in the MaxUsers column to represent no maximum amount

This query will show you whether the group rules have passed or not.

```
select r.id, r.Name, gr.GroupId,
    case when x.GroupQty>=isnull(gr.MinUsers, x.GroupQty) 
      and x.GroupQty<=isnull(gr.MaxUsers, x.GroupQty) 
    then 1 else 0 end as GroupValid
from #ruleset r
join #ruleset_Grouprules gr on gr.RuleId=r.Id
join (
    select g.groupID, count(*) GroupQty
    from #Groups g
    join #PersonGroups pg on pg.GroupID=g.GroupID
    join #Persons p on p.PersonID=pg.PersonID
    group by g.GroupID
)x on x.GroupID=gr.GroupID
```

You can then aggregate on this query to compare `sum(GroupValid)=count(*)` with a `group by r.id` to check if the entire Rule is valid. I left it like that so you can see the working data.

Comment: Haven't tried it all the way, but it seems that this will count a single person multiple times if he belongs to multiple groups. In the example (2) will satisfy that there is a person from all the groups present, as he belong to all 3 groups.

Comment: Just noticed I haven't catered for the only one person can apply for one group condition. Will update shortly.

Comment: JNK is right you need to use a recursive CTE to generate all possible combinations of users and their respective groups then check the generated results to determine whether you have satisfied your rules. I'm using SQL 2000 and I can't do it without a loop of some sort.